# Monte Carlo Simulation using TOPAS, how to make a hollow sphere

Tags: montecarlo

I am trying to use TOPAS to create a geometric system that is a hollow sphere scorer around a point radiation source in a water world.
I have gotten everything to work, except the sphere is solid.

I have looked at the TOPAS documentation/Manual and I see there are examples for making a TsSphere (which is what I initually used), and for G4HPolycone which generates a hollow polycone and you can define the inner and outer dimensions.

I experimented a bit with terms like "G4HSphere" and "TsHSphere" on the off chance it just wasn't mentioned in that specific document (with RInner and ROuter defined as 9.5 and 10.5 respectively) but neither of those terms worked and resulted in termination of the code.

Any insight for how to make a hollow sphere is much appreciated :)

Comment: Could you explain what TOPAS is? That might help other people with the same question since there's no tag for it at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - TsSphere still works, but adding the variables Rmin and Rmax then allows you to make that sphere hollow :)